# 'While' condition is not satisfied

Tags: python, while-loop

i am having a bit of trouble understanding why the "while" loop in my code doesn't stop when the condition is met.

```
"""
:param duration: how long the loop will last in hours
:param time_pause: every x seconds the loop restarts
"""
time_start = readTime()
time_now = readTime()
time_end = time_start.hour + duration
time_sleep = conf.SETTINGS["LIGHT_UNTIL"]
print('Time when the script was started \n', time_start)
print('Script ends', time_end)

try:
    while time_now.hour <= time_end or time_now.hour < time_sleep:
        temp.read_temp_humidity()
        lights.Lights_Time()
        water.water_plants_1ch(ch_number=2, time_water=2)
        time.sleep(time_pause)
        time_now = readTime()

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # here you put any code you want to run before the program
    # exits when you press CTRL+C
    print("Keyboard interrupt \n", readTime())  # print value of counter`
```

The readTime() function uses this:

```
try:
    ds3231 = SDL_DS3231.SDL_DS3231(1, 0x68)
    print( "DS3231=\t\t%s" % ds3231.read_datetime() )
    print( "DS3231 Temp=", ds3231.getTemp() )
    return ds3231.read_datetime()

except:        # alternative: return the system-time:
    print("Raspberry Pi=\t" + time.strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ) )
    return datetime.utcnow()`
```

The first condition of the while loop is never met and the loop ends only on the second condition.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: I think you may have used the wrong boolean.  You used or, which means either one of those conditions will keep the while loop going.  I think you wanted either one coming false to get you out, in which case you should use and because you want to keep going only if both are true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is evident from your code that, you are using an 'OR' between these conditions as in (x or y).
So the loop will continue its execution until both of these conditions equate to a false value.

ex : Consider the following while loop

```
       `while( x || y) 
        {
             //Do something
        }`
```

Here the loop will continue to function as long as any one among x or y continue to
return true, the exit condition is when both x & y returns false.(NB : x & y are
assumed to be 2 different conditions in the pseudo code)

you said : "The first condition of the while loop is never met and the loop ends only on the second condition". From this I infer that, the first condition('time_now.hour <= time_end') is always false and the control flow exits the loop only when the second condition('time_now.hour < time_sleep') also becomes false.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS**

1. You calculate 'time_end' as 'time_start.hour + duration'. So here you might have to check whether the variable 'duration' actually holds the correct/expected value, see if you ran into any errors in the calculation of 'duration'.
2. If you want the looping to stop when any one of the conditions is false, then you must use an 'and' operator instead of an 'or'.

   ex : Consider the following while loop

   ```
      `while( x && y)
       {
            //Do something
       }`
   ```

   Here the loop will continue to function as long as both x and y continue to return
   true, the exit condition is when any one among them returns false.(NB : x & y
   are assumed to be 2 different conditions in the pseudo code)
3. You should ensure that the variables in the looping conditions are getting updated in accordance with your intended logic on looping, any errors in the dynamic calculation of the variables that determine the looping condition will yield the wrong result, for example in your code the looping variables for your first condition are 'time_now.hour' and 'time_end', so make sure they are getting updated with the intended values on looping(you might have any logical errors in the calculation).

I think your issue will be fixed on following solution 1 given above.

Comment: Thank you all - I realize it was a silly mistake. Appreciate all the good explanation.